# Reprojection function fails in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r

My aim is to reproject two R objects to a common CRs, but I keep running into this error

***Error***

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string<-’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "CRS"’
```

This is my code

```
setwd("H:/R")
library("rgdal")
library("sp")#Shiet. I just loaded more than one library in one sentence. It didn't work though
library("rgeos")
library("ggplot2")
library("raster")
Census.Data <-read.csv("practicaldata.csv")
Polygon.Data <- readOGR(dsn = "H:/R", layer = "Camden_oa11")
House.Data <-  readOGR("Camden_house_sales")
Polygons.Census <- merge(Census.data, Polygon.Data, by.x ="OA", by.y ="OA11CD")
proj4string(Polygons.Census) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:27700")
proj4string(House.Data) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:27700")
```

What could be causing the error?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you are trying to use the proj4string in a wrong way. You can try  `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame()` to convert the data directly into polygon where you can set `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(data=House.Data,proj4string = CRS("+init=EPSG:27700")`

Comment: You are strongly advised to not use the `sp` package any more, it is being retired (along with `rgdal` and `rgeos`) soon. Find a tutorial on using the `sf` package for spatial data - you probably then need functions like `st_read` to load your spatial data and `st_transform` to reproject it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've constructed some simple sample data (something you should always do in questions here so we can reproduce your problem) and I can get your error on this line (you don't tell us which line is your problem but let's see if its this):

```
> proj4string(Polygons.Census) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:27700")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string<-’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "CRS"’
```

Reading the error message tells us its trying to find a function for setting `proj4string` where the first argument is a `data.frame` and the second is a `CRS`. So `Polygons.Census` at this point is a data frame, and not a spatial data frame. How is this happening?

`Polygons.Census` is created like this:

```
Polygons.Census <- merge(Census.Data, Polygon.Data, by.x ="OA", by.y ="OA11CD")
```

(note you have `Census.data` and `Census.Data` and these are two different objects, but you'd get a different error if one doesn't exist so I'll assume you've got two copies of the same data because you've been inconsistent with `.data` and `.Data`).

Here `Census.Data` is a plain data frame read in from a CSV file. You've merged the spatial data, and with `merge` like this the returned object is the same type as the first argument, `Census.Data`. Its a plain data frame. This has dropped the spatial nature of the object, so you can't set a CRS for it because its not spatial, and R gives the error saying this.

If you do the merge the other way round you get a spatial object:

```
> class(merge(Polygon.Data, Census.Data, by.x="OA11CD",by.y="OA"))
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Compared with this way round, plain data frame:

```
> class(merge(Census.Data, Polygon.Data, by.y="OA11CD",by.x="OA"))
[1] "data.frame"
```

Depending on the nature of the merge, this may be what you meant to do, to create a new spatial object with attributes taken from matching OAs in the census data.

Once you've done this this way round you can assign a coordinate system if the data has a wrong system already, or use `spTransform` to convert the coordinates. You've not shown which coordinates the data is in so I'm not going to show you this, maybe ask a new question about transforming spatial data if you can't get this to work. But I should have given you enough information to do the merge.

Also **STRONG** recommendation to install and use the `sf` package for spatial data since `sp` and friends are going away soon.

Comment: I merged starting with Spatial data ```Polygon.Data ```then plain data frame ```Census.Data``` and it worked.

Comment: Thankyou @Spacedman. I merged starting with Spatial data `Polygon.Data` then plain data frame `Census.Data` and the error is now sorted. Also thanks for the reminder to use latest packages, the tutorial I am using to learn R is based on old packages.